Prove matrix constructed based on gaussian RBF is PSD
I have a radial basis function $k(x, y) = \exp(-{(x-y)}^T M {(x-y)})$ where $M$ is a symmetric PSD matrix.
I know that $k(\cdot)$ is a kernel itself: Prove that multiplication with positive semidefinite matrix is a kernel
According to definition of PSD kernel, I guess I can say the matrix $K$ which is $n\times n$ and its entries are $k_{ij}=k(x_i, x_j)$ is positive semi definite. But I don't know how to prove that.
Actually my advisor believes that the resulting matrix $K$ is not PSD with this construction and he blamed me an entire hour because I am a grad student yet I don't know the difference between PSD kernel and PSD matrix. He just pull out this matrix as a counter example and said that all I'm saying is wrong because this is a counter example:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0.9 & 0.6 \\
0.9 & 1 & 0.9 \\
0.6 & 0.9 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $$
Which has a negative eigenvalue. I really believe that I'm thinking right but I just cannot prove that. Can you help me with a prove of that and also if I am right then why this counter example exists?

Is $| \cdot |$ some norm? Because $| x - y|$ is a scalar, all you're doing is rescaling $M$ by the quantity $| x - y|^2$, implying that $k(x,y)$ outputs a matrix. The more typical RBF is a quadratic form, so $(x - y)^T M (x-y)$ is vector-matrix-vector multiplication.

@Sycorax Oh my bad, you're right. I edited the question.

How is the matrix a counter-example? What are the values of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $M$ that yield this result?

I don't know either to be honest. I mean can we prove that there is no $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $M$ that produce such counter example?

That's one possibility. It's not much of a counter-example if the professor doesn't know which values produce that matrix. You might want to start from the simpler case of scalar $M$. But essentially, there's 3 points and you can work backwards to get the distances between them (up to a scalar multiple $M$). So they should obey the triangle inequality.

I don't know how to convince my professor, he just said: "I will design $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $M$ that produce these numbers. It's fairly easy, given the large degrees of freedom"

Allow me to offer you some unsollicited advice Biri. The problem you are facing is not a technical problem about the postive-definiteness of mathematical objects. Rather, you have an interpersonal relations/communications problem about the relationship between you and your advisor. I suspect what you are really looking for is for someone here to tell you that you are right and your advisor is wrong. But this is not going to fix the fundamental communications issues, which will continue to be the true problem until you address them.

@JohnMadden Thanks John, I think you are right. He already told me the same thing that you said.
